# python access mysql table using mysql+mysqlconnector read text type problem

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql-connector-python

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@127.0.0.1/superset?charset=utf8')

query = 'select dm,yoy from swy_test'
data = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
data
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `swy_test` (
  `dm` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `country` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `type` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `yoy` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

How to fix it? `b'2019-01' ==> 2019-01`, desired effect as below

[image]

Comment: Upload csv in superset UI, and data is normal, because if  query in Datagrip, it's ok

Comment: The problem is that the table has a binary collation, so the connector returns binary data. `select dm collate utf8mb4_general_ci, yoy collate utf8mb4_general_ci from swy_test` would work, but probably you should change the collations on the table and its columns to a text collation such as utf8mb4_general_ci ( MySQL 5.7) or utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (MySQL 8.0).

Comment: @snakecharmerb But the same table, if connect mysql by this way `mysql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{database}`  it's ok

Comment: `mysql://` will use the MySQLdb connector package - presumably it's more lenient in this situation.